# Creating PDFs and the default printer

Tags: pdf

When you create a PDF is the default printer used at the time it is created to determine how to format it for pages and margins?

Comment: Not programming-related.

Comment: It is if you're using a reporting tool, in which case the answer is probably yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What technology/library are you using to create the PDF?

Reporting tools generally look at the default printer parameters.

Comment: I have a used a couple of reporting tools in the past (but not Crystal Reports) and these have taken the default printer settings into account when generating reports.

Answer (score 1):

It is a pain to distribute an application that depends on a default printer to determine the format of pdf automation. At first, it seems robust, but then the calls come in saying that something odd is happening to the reports. This is a real issue for the amateur Office programmer. Of course, we probably shouldn't exist, but there are more of us than one would expect.

I don't have a clear answer. I can only say find the default printer settings that cause the issue, and work around it either manually or programmatically. This cannot be accomplished by simply checking for service pack updates, if-then-else, and going about your business. You need an appropriate printer driver installed!